# Moving Django 1.6 to new server

Tags: python, django, centos

I'm wondering what steps are evolved in moving a django project to a new server. 
basicly i'm completely new to Django and have a few questions. The server it is on is now is not stable so I need to act fast. I did not build the app that is there but have pulled down the www folder from the root server. The server is running centOS.

Questions.
is Django backwards compatible or will I need to insure that the same version is installed?

Apart from moving the files what other steps are involved in running the app?

Will I need to use centOS or will any linux server do?

I have a database cluster of PostgreSQL ready to go also.

Comment: This depends on so many things, it can't be answered

Answer (score 2):

Start with [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/) - this will give you a  good overview.

To your specific questions:

1/ Django is not backwards compatible. You should install 1.6.x. Likely, there's a `requirements.txt` file in the root directory of your app. On your new server, install pip and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install your dependencies. I would personally use [`virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage your dependencies on the server

2/ Check the docs, but the main steps are:

1. Choose a web server. I personally use nginx. You'll need to setup your nginx.conf.
2. Choose a Python WSGI HTTP Server - I use gunicorn. You'll also need to configure this. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) is a great place to start.
3. If you use the DigitalOcean tutorial above, any linux server will do. Last, you'll need to upload your Postgres database to the server but sounds like you're able to do that.

3/ You will need to edit your `settings.py` of the Django project and update certain variables.

1. If you're changing your database, as well as the app deployment, you'll need to edit the database connection, run `./manage.py syncdb` and `./manage.py migrate` (if you're using South) to set up the database schema.
2. It's also recommended to change the `SECRET_KEY` between deployments.
3. If you're deploying on a different hosts, you'll need to edit `ALLOWED_HOSTS` appropriately for your new deployment as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer, I'll follow all of those steps :)